# Problema al hacer clearInterval después de realizar varios setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

He hecho un programa pero me gustaría saber cómo puedo dejarlo mejor (no lo tengo por qué hacer, pero es por curiosidad).

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var llistaColors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow","red","purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
var llistaNomColors =["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];
/**
*   iniColors s'executa al carregar la pagina.
*   Pinta a la pagina els colors que tenim a la llistaColors 
*/
function iniColors(){
  for (i=0; i<llistaColors.length;i++){
    pintaColors(i, llistaColors[i]);
  }
}
function mouColorsEsquerra(){ 
  llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);  
  iniColors();
}
function iniciaRotacio(){
  llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);  
  iniColors();
  btnRotate = true;
  myVar = setInterval(function(){
    llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
    llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop());  
    updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);
    iniColors();
  }, 100);    
}
function aturaRotacio(){
  clearInterval(myVar);
}
function pintaColors(i, color){
  var colorDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.colordiv');
  colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function updateColorName(name){
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('primerColor');
  currentColor.textContent = name;
} 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var btnRotate = document.getElementById('brotar1'); 
});
```

```css
.contenedorColors {
  margin-bottom:100px;
}
.colordiv {
  float:left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border:  1px solid black;
}
.info {
  clear:left;
  margin-top:20px;
}
.info button {
  background-color: white; /* Green */
  border:  2px solid #555555;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.info p {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#colorDetall {
  display:none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 340px;
}

.repte {
  float:left;
  visibility:hidden; 
}
.colorRepte {
  clear:left;
  margin-left:150px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border:  1px solid black;
}

.repte p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left:50px;
}


/*estils finestra repteResultats */

#contenedor {
  text-align: center;
}

.lletraGran {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.missatge {
  display:none;
}

.estadistiques-taula{
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="iniColors()">
  <h1>Mou colors (3ra versió)</h1>
  <div id="contenedorColors" class="contenedorColors">
    <div id="color0" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color1" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color2" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color3" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color4" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color5" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color6" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color7" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color8" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="color9" class="colordiv"></div>
    <div id="repte" class="repte">
      <div id="colorRepte" class="colorRepte"></div>
      <p>Repte: Atura'l en aquest color </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="info">
    <p>
      <button id="brotar1" type="button" onclick="mouColorsEsquerra()">rotar 1</button>
      <button id="brotar" type="button" onclick="iniciaRotacio()">rotar (&lt;&lt;)</button>
      <button id="bparar" type="button" onclick="aturaRotacio()">aturar</button>
    </p>
    <p>Primer color: <span id="primerColor"></span></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Cuando le doy a rotar (botón "rotar 1") es perfecto. Pero cuando le doy al botón "rotar (<<)" (que llama a `iniciaRotacio()`), el problema que tengo es que al darle tendría que encenderlo (cosa que hace), pero si lo aprieto nuevamente no debería acelerarlo.

El problema me viene que al pulsar en "aturar" (para parar `iniciaRotacio()`), si le he dado varias a "rotar (<<)" veces, no me funciona. ¿Hay alguna forma para que al darle a iniciaRotacio() lo haga funcionar solo una vez?

Comment: voy a ello ahora lo edito! ;)

Comment: ya esta editado, ahora podrás verlo mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo que puedes hacer:

- Define la variable `myVar` y asígnale el valor `null`
- En la función `iniciaRotacio` comprueba si `myVar` está definida
- Cuando hagas el `clearInterval`, vuelve a poner `myVar` con el valor `null`

De este modo estarás creando un "semáforo" que comprobará que el `setInterval` sólo se pueda llamar una vez en lugar de múltiples veces (que es el problema que te estás encontrando).

Tu código con esos cambios se vería así:

```js
var llistaColors = ["grey", "black", "blue", "yellow","red","purple", "green", "white", "orange", "pink"];
var llistaNomColors =["Gris", "negre", "blau", "Groc", "Vermell", "lila", "Verd", "blanc", "Taronja", "rosa"];
var myVar = null;  // define myVar e inicializa a null
/**
*   iniColors s'executa al carregar la pagina.
*   Pinta a la pagina els colors que tenim a la llistaColors 
*/
function iniColors(){
 for (i=0; i<llistaColors.length;i++){
    pintaColors(i, llistaColors[i]);
  }
}
function mouColorsEsquerra(){ 
  llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);  
  iniColors();
}
function iniciaRotacio(){
  if (!myVar) { // comprueba que myVar no esté definida
 llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
  llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop()); 
  updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);  
  iniColors();
   btnRotate = true;
 myVar = setInterval(function(){
   llistaColors.unshift(llistaColors.pop());
   llistaNomColors.unshift(llistaNomColors.pop());  
   updateColorName(llistaNomColors[0]);
   iniColors();
   }, 100);    
    }
}
function aturaRotacio(){
  clearInterval(myVar);
  myVar = null;  // pon myVar a null
}

function pintaColors(i, color){
  var colorDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.colordiv');
    colorDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
function updateColorName(name){
  var currentColor = document.getElementById('primerColor');
    currentColor.textContent = name;
} 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var btnRotate = document.getElementById('brotar1'); 
});
```

```css
.contenedorColors {
 margin-bottom:100px;
}
.colordiv {
 float:left;
 height: 40px;
 width: 40px;
 border:  1px solid black;
}
.info {
 clear:left;
 margin-top:20px;
}
.info button {
    background-color: white; /* Green */
    border:  2px solid #555555;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.info p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#colorDetall {
 display:none;
 width: 600px;
    height: 340px;
}

.repte {
 float:left;
    visibility:hidden; 
}
.colorRepte {
 clear:left;
 margin-left:150px;
 height: 60px;
 width: 60px;
 border:  1px solid black;
}

.repte p {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left:50px;
}


/*estils finestra repteResultats */

#contenedor {
 text-align: center;
}

.lletraGran {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px gray;
}

.missatge {
 display:none;
}

.estadistiques-taula{
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Mou Colors (3ra versió)</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="colors.css">
  <script src="js/colors3.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="iniColors()">
  <h1>Mou colors (3ra versió)</h1>
  <div id="contenedorColors" class="contenedorColors">
   <div id="color0" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color1" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color2" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color3" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color4" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color5" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color6" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color7" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color8" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="color9" class="colordiv"></div>
   <div id="repte" class="repte">
    <div id="colorRepte" class="colorRepte"></div>
    <p>Repte: Atura'l en aquest color </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="info" class="info">
   <p>
    <button id="brotar1" type="button" onclick="mouColorsEsquerra()">rotar 1</button>
    <button id="brotar" type="button" onclick="iniciaRotacio()">rotar (&lt;&lt;)</button>
    <button id="bparar" type="button" onclick="aturaRotacio()">aturar</button>
   </p>
   <p>Primer color: <span id="primerColor"><span></p>
   <p>
    <button id="bdetall"type="button" onclick="gestioDetall()">mostra detall</button> 
   </p>
  </div>
  <iframe id="colorDetall" src=""></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ooh!! Era super sencillo.. a veces me complico demasiado.. gracias!!